# Which kernel function does on-demand module loading triggered by accessing a non-existent device node under /dev?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

In `/usr/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.devname`, the first line is a comment:

```
# Device nodes to trigger on-demand module loading.
```

Assuming what it means is that the first time a device file under `/dev` is accessed, a module which populates that file will be automatically loaded.

But I don't see the code that does module loading when a file lookup failed, in `/drivers/base/devtmpfs.c` or `/mm/shmem.c`(tmpfs). Where does that logic live then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `modules.devname` file has nothing to do with module auto-loading. It contains information that can be used during system initialization to create files in the `/dev` directory. The file is read by the `kmod static-nodes` command. By default, `kmod static-nodes` produces human-readable output, but during system initialization it is run as `kmod static-nodes --format=tmpfiles` to generate output in a more machine-parseable form. Each line contains information that can be used to create a single directory or a single special file (see the `tmpfiles.d` man page for details of the format). It does not contain the module name.

On systems using Systemd init, the `kmod` command is run from the `kmod-static-nodes.service` service. The output file in `tmpfiles.d` format is placed in "/run/tmpfiles.d/static-nodes.conf", which will be read later by the `systemd-tmpfiles --prefix=/dev --create --boot` command run from the `systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service` service to create the actual files in "/dev".

On systems using Sysv init, the `kmod` command may be run by the `/etc/init.d/udev` init script (on Debian type systems) or from somewhere else.  The same init script creates the actual files in "/dev" based on the output from `kmod`.

---

When a *character special* file for an unregistered character device number is being opened, the kernel will request the module with alias `char-major-MAJOR-MINOR` or `char-major-MAJOR` where `MAJOR` and `MINOR` are the major and minor device numbers of the special file.  (See `base_probe()` in "fs/char_dev.c".)  If the kernel is configured with `CONFIG_BLOCK_LEGACY_AUTOLOAD=y`, there is similar functionality when opening *block special* files for unregistered block device numbers, the kernel will request the module with alias `block-major-MAJOR-MINOR` or `block-major-MAJOR`.  (See `blk_request_module()` in "block/genhd.c" and `blkdev_get_no_open()` in "block/bdev.c".)

The source code for a module uses the `MODULE_ALIAS_CHARDEV()`, `MODULE_ALIAS_CHARDEV_MAJOR()`, `MODULE_ALIAS_BLOCKDEV()`, or `MODULE_ALIAS_BLOCKDEV_MAJOR()` macros (which wrap the `MODULE_ALIAS()` macro) to put these aliases into the module's `.modinfo` section where the `depmod` command can find them.

Comment: For reference, [here's the relevant piece of code in `misc_open()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10/source/drivers/char/misc.c#L118) asking for the module to be loaded by the kernel. The loading itself is done through [kmod](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10/source/kernel/kmod.c) which invokes `modprobe` through `call_usermodehelper_exec`.

Comment: @Ian Your explanations make a lot of sense. One question though, I found `dm_interface_init()` from `dm-ioctl.c`, which actually registers and adds `/dev/mapper/control` by eventually calling `device_register()/device_add()/devtmpfs_create_node()`. If `dm_interface_init()` is called upon module `dm-mod` loading, then isn't that duplicating the creation of node `/dev/mapper/control` which is already made by systemd-tmpfiles service?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Thanks for the additional location for module loading, although the one in `misc_open()` is only used for char major 10 (misc) devices.

Comment: @QnA Indeed, the `devtmpfs_create_node(dev);` call from `device_add(dev)` will return `-EEXIST` but the error is ignored. However, when the `dm-mod` module is unloaded (which will remove the control device), the `/dev/mapper/control` file (and `/dev/mapper` directory) will be deleted, which seems like a bug. (The same problem does not occur with the "nvram" module, for example, because it doesn't set the `nodename` member of its `struct miscdevice`.)

Comment: @Ian All clear now, thanks a ton!